# FacesServlet not found on deploy

Tags: jsf, tomcat, netbeans, primefaces

I have a sample application which works on my local machine using Netbeans with GlassFish. I received a lot of help from StackOverflow getting it up and running. The next step is to try and deploy it on a real server. I found I could try it on EATJ so I used Netbeans to generate a WAR file and I uploaded the WAR file. It doesn't work and I found the following in one of the logs

```
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Jun 12, 2012 10:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Faces Servlet as unavailable
Jun 12, 2012 10:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ww1 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
```

I just restarted the Tomcat server so that I would have a clean slate. I can see from the time stamp that I am synchronized. In the INFO it is telling me that it is making Faces Servlet unavailable. So it is hardly surprising that it can't find the class if it just made it unavailable. Thus when I try to run my application, it fails.

What I fail to understand is why it decided to make it unavailable in the first place, and what I can do about it.

In Netbeans on my local machine I am using GlassFish and on EATJ Tomcat is being used. Is something built into the WAR file which could make it not run on Tomcat? Hard to believe, but maybe. I am using jsf 2.0 with primefaces if that should make any difference.

I have never run Tomcat on my local machine since GlassFish came bundled with Netbeans and it worked just fine. Maybe I have to load Tomcat on my local machine to test it? I don't know what to think, so I need to ask some advice.

P.S. I remember that I added glassfish-web.xml to remove an annoying warning. The line I added was

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Perhaps I need to remove the glassfish-web.xml? On the other hand what does it have to do with making FacesServlet unavailable? The problem seems deeper than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glassfish comes with bundled jsf libs. Tomcat doesn't. So you either need to put jsf libs to tomcat libs or add them to your war file when you build project.
You can download jsf [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html).

Comment: That is what I call a very nice answer. I wanted to check it before answering and it works! My site is up and running. I took the approach of adding the jsf to my war file and it solves the problem.